# Converting Mysql result set to JSON prints same fields twice

Tags: php, mysql, json

this is the php:

```
function getReadings($conn) {
    $sql = $conn->prepare('Call getSensorReadings');
    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->fetchAll();
    print json_encode($result);
}
$conn = connectUsingRoot();
getReadings($conn);
```

However when I run this I get data like:

```
{
0: "Source1",
1: "36.11",
2: "19.39",
3: "2016-03-16 19:24:28",
source: "Source1",
temp: "36.11",
mois: "19.39",
timestamp: "2016-03-16 19:24:28"
}
```

The MySQL is simply:

```
SELECT      sourceName as source,
            tempValue as temp,
            moisValue as mois,
            creation_time as 'timestamp'

FROM        Reading r
ORDER BY    creation_time;
```

Why does it add the extra fields? Is the query running twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `fetchAll` first argument to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. As by default it's set to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which gives you this output.

```
$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) about `FETCH`-parameters

Comment: I tried that now I get:
Notice: Use of undefined constant FETCH_ASSOC - assumed 'FETCH_ASSOC' in getReadings.php on line 25.

do I need to define FETCH_ASSOC?

Comment: Nevermind, it should be:

$result = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
public array PDOStatement::fetchAll ([ int $fetch_style [, mixed $fetch_argument [, array $ctor_args = array() ]]] )
```

> PDO::FETCH_BOTH (default): returns an array indexed by both column
>   name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

Use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC for this statement:

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or change the global behavior:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```